# Making modifications to an Android List View (globally)

Tags: android

Is there a way to make modifications to a ListView in an app on Android that you don't have access too?
The app has vertical padding between the listview elements. I have a rooted phone. My goal is to somehow find a way to remove the padding in the listview elements without touching the code or decompiling the apk. Similar to how one can create a global font-size, it it possible to create global setting applicable to the ListView class?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find that way.
Because it is theoretically impossible.
I don't know why you might need such a method, but your request is certainly unclear for millions android developers.

Comment: According to my understanding Android is open-source and root access gives you a plethora of room to navigate in terms of hacking/customization. So I'm thinking there must be a way to make something like that?